# how to open and save a file in scroll area widget with pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

here i changed this code according to  my program,i got an error can you please help me how to rectify this error

```
def save_file(self):

        self.contents =QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.w = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        filename, filter = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent=self, caption='Open file', dir='.', filter='csv file(*.csv)')

        if filename:
            self.contents.setText(filename.read())


        self.lay.addWidget(self.contents)
        self.w.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.w)
```

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: what is `self`? what is your problem?

Comment: i am getting my text in command prompt but i want to save a file in scroll area widget  but i don't know how to save a file in scroll area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following errors:

- `scrollArea` is a widget that is not part of the `w` widget, so it will not show, so there are 2 possible solutions: make it son of w and resize its size manually, or use a layout, in this case use the second.
- When you read a file with `f.read()` you delete it from the buffer f, that is, if you call `f.read()` it will not return anything since the cursor is at the end of the file, so it is printed on the console but it will not show up in the QTextEdit.
- You have some typographical errors.

Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
    scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
    lay.addWidget(scrollArea)
    textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    scrollArea.setWidget(textEdit)
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(w, 'Open File', '/')
    if filename:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            textEdit.setText(f.read())
    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc change `filename = ...` to `filename, _ = ...`

Comment: @S.Nick please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041271/is-there-a-difference-between-qfiledialog-strings-in-pyqt4-and-pyqt5

Comment: @S.Nick Do not worry, it usually happens :-)