# PyQt4 Qstring to PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

In PyQt4 this is printed :

> ```
>     s_filePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
>         None,
>         'Select a File',
>         'C:\\')
>     print("This is the file",s_filePath)
> ```
>
> **('This is the file',PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'C:/script.txt'))**

In PyQt5 this is printed :

> ```
>     s_filePath = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
>         None,
>         'Select a File',
>         'C:\\')
>     print("This is the file",s_filePath)
> ```
>
> **This is the file ('C:/script.txt', 'All Files (*)')**

In PyQt4 version is working but PyQt5 is not , Whats the equivalent of PyQt4.QtCore.QString in PyQt5 ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041271/is-there-a-difference-between-qfiledialog-strings-in-pyqt4-and-pyqt5/47041565#47041565

Comment: @S.Nick Thanks alot